# ABL (http://www.progress.com/en/openedge/abl.html) Progress

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I would like to learn  ABL(http://www.progress.com/en/openedge/abl.html).
Do you have any Idea what I have to install to be able to practice it at home.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.progresstalk.com/showthread.php?120527-Loads-of-Progress-info-and-documentation-links

Answer (score 1):

You want the evaluation kit download.

http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-103695

Answer (score 1):

yes this hand book will be good to start with

http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-16296

Answer (score 1):

In OpenEdge 11.6 Progress added a free classroom edition. You need to create an account but there are no costs involved.
https://www.progress.com/openedge/classroom-edition